# Why do MPFR initialization functions work even though they take unintialized values and return nothing instead of using a pointer?

Tags: c, semantics, mpfr

I was recently recommended the library MPFR by a friend. Looking at it, I’m severely confused as to how it’s supposed to work—it doesn’t mesh with my understanding of C at all. To initialize an MPFR value it is suggested to write something like this:

```c
mpfr_t number;
mpfr_init2(number, 1000);
```

How does this function communicate its output? It merely receives a[n] (unintialized) value of type `mpfr_t` and gives nothing back. To communicate back it’d have to take a pointer, right? I first checked in the source code to see if it was a macro but it doesn’t seem to be (unless `__MPFR_DECLSPEC` is black magic, but it seems to expand to nothing).

The only possibilities I can think of are: 1) MPFR somehow gets the address of the `mpfr_t` (on the stack) and modifies that directly. But this seems like it *should* be impossible or only possible via technically undefined behaviour. 2) `mpfr_t` is actually a pointer and through some quirk unintialized pointers are initialized to point to the stack. But this seems unlikely.

What the hell is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mpfr_t` is an array of size 1.

So you pass the reference (pointer) to the first element of this array as arrays decay to pointers if used in expressions.

It is one of the "organic" examples of why hiding pointers and arrays behind the `typedef` is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

It is the second option, the mpfr_t is in fact an array (pointer). See its definition.